# Angular JS - Using ng-show to show something based on complex requirements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning Angular JS, and I need a way to use `ng-show` to show a line of text by considering the following:

1.) If both number fields have been filled in, display the line of text.

2.) If both number fields have been filled in but both are 0, display the line of text.

3.) If both number fields have been filled in and one is 0 but the other is a different number, display the text.

This is my code so far:

```
<p ng-show="(firstNumber && secondNumber) || (firstNumber == 0 && secondNumber == 0)">
    The product is {{firstNumber * secondNumber}}
</p>
```

Right now, this line of code fulfills requirements 1 and 2, but when 0 is entered and another number is entered which is not zero, the line of text doesn't show.

Any ideas on how to get this done? I feel like the conditional operation statement will be pretty complex.

I think I should include more of my code since many seem to assume that I have "text" as the input type when I have "number". This is probably why Charlie's solution isn't working:

```
<p>Enter first number: <input type="number" ng-model="firstNumber"></p>
<p>Enter second number: <input type="number" ng-model="secondNumber" /></p>
```

Comment: Need to realize that when variable is zero `if(variable)` is false

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. That's the reason I put in the `(firstNumber == 0 && secondNumber == 0)`. Because it wasn't displaying when I wanted to do 0 times 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collective logic of all your requirements is to see if both fields are numbers.

```
<p ng-show="isNumber(firstNumber) && isNumber(secondNumber))">
    The product is {{firstNumber * secondNumber}}
</p>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.isNumber = function(value) {
   return !isNaN(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems logical that this should work, but it starts out my page with the text displaying. It seems that this code should not make it, but it does anyway. I think I should note that I'm using AngularJS version 1.2

Comment: That is because you are initializing your `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` with probably zero in the controller. Initialize them with a non-number. This will solve the problem.

Comment: does isNaN avaiable on view if you don't bind it on scope ?

Comment: @Anik - It is not available. Thanks. Answer updated.

Comment: @CharlieH Is it possible to check if firstNumber != null or secondNumber != null? I feel like it should work but I don't know if that's allowed in the braces. Keep in mind that I'm still a beginner so sorry for so many questions.

Comment: If you check it for `null` a value like `'cat'` will return true

Comment: See my updated question, I think it will clarify things

Comment: But just to clarify, the input type of the field is "number" and not text, so a 'cat' value cannot be entered, only numbers.

Comment: What is the error you get by employing my solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100443/discussion-between-rafi-and-charlie-h).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to encapsulate every piece of *complex* logic into a function method of your controller or better yet a model i.e.:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.isResultVisible = function(){
    return $scope.firstNumber >= 0 && $scope.secondNumber >= 0;
  };
  $scope.result = function(){
    return $scope.firstNumber * $scope.secondNumber;
  };
});
```

And then use it inside of markup:

```
<p ng-show="isResultVisible()">
    The product is {{result()}}
</p>
```